# Restrict output of fields in Django admin according to previous selection

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I have this model.py:

```
class Funder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    scheme = models.ManyToManyField('Scheme', blank=True)
    
class Scheme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200))

class Project(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    funder = models.ForeignKey(Funder)
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(Scheme, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

A funder can have 0, 1, or many `scheme`s attached to it. I'd like to limit the choice of schemes that can be selected from the admin form for `project` to only the `scheme`s that belong to a specific funder. Is that possible?

Example:

in 'new project', people select funder1, and only see scheme1, scheme3, scheme5 in the drop-down for scheme, because scheme2 and scheme4 are associated to funder2.

Is this something that can be obtained with a `QuerySet`?

My `ModelAdmin`:

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
class FunderAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name',]
    autocomplete_fields = ['scheme']
    list_display = ("name",)
```

Comment: I was correcting when you were posting the comment, thank you. That was a copy-paste from a previous test.

Comment: Is the funder somehow related to the logged in user? Can you share the current `ModelAdmin` (probably you use a `TabularInline` or something?)?

Comment: No, I don't use `TabularInLine`. I'll add my `ModelAdmin`, which doesn't have anything fancy though.

Comment: And no, the funder is not related to the logged-in user. It doesn't have anything to do with authentication or permissions.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem PPS: actually, I only have one funder for the project, so my original question remains valid. Ho can I restrict the choices of schemes when I select one funder from the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [smart-selects](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). I can immediately warn you in `settings.py` use `USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True` instead of: `JQUERY_URL = True`. I checked your models, the `scheme` selection field is limited depending on which `funder` is selected.

models.py

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    funder = models.ForeignKey(Funder, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    scheme = ChainedForeignKey(
        Scheme,
        chained_field="funder",
        chained_model_field="funder",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
]
```

Alternatively, you can pass the data to the javascript `function` and try to filter it. But, so far I’ve only managed to register `event` processing in the form widget and get the selected `funder`, but I can’t pass the data to the javascript(Just in case, I provide the form below, **it does not apply to the first working version**):

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'funder': forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': "Load();"})
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, @inquirer! I solved my issue by using `smart-selects`. I tweaked the URL changing it to `re_path(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this with the current schema, is bit dependent on overriding Django admin
So I am posting a solution where you just need to add a fetching route and function
and override Django admin js a bit (**without any third party dependency**).

Assuming you have models like this:

```
class Scheme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.name}"

class Funder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    scheme = models.ManyToManyField(Scheme, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.name}"

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    funder = models.ForeignKey(Funder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(Scheme, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.title}"
```

Project admin.py changes will look like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from funder.models import Funder
from .models import Project

from django.urls import path
from django.http import JsonResponse


class ProjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "title", "funder", "scheme")
    list_filter = ("funder",)
    search_fields = ("title",)
    ordering = ("title",)

    class Media:
        # Include JavaScript files in the admin panel
        js = ("js/admin_project.js",)

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(ProjectAdmin, self).get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path(
                "fetch_schemes/",
                self.fetch_schemes,
                name="project_project_fetch_schemes",
            ),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls

    def fetch_schemes(self, request):
        funder_id = request.GET.get("funder_id")
        if funder_id:
            try:
                funder = Funder.objects.get(id=funder_id)
                schemes = list(funder.scheme.all().values("id", "name"))
                return JsonResponse({"schemes": schemes})
            except Funder.DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({"error": "Funder not found"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"error": "Funder ID not provided"})


admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

Now just add js/admin_project.js in your static folder of Django

```
// admin_project.js

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Store the current value of the scheme dropdown
    var currentSchemeValue = $('#id_scheme').val();

    $('#id_funder').change(function() {
        var funderId = $(this).val();
        
        if (funderId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/project/project/fetch_schemes/?funder_id=" + funderId,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Empty the scheme dropdown and add an empty option
                    $('#id_scheme').empty().append('<option value="">---</option>');
                    // Append schemes from the data
                    $.each(data.schemes, function (index, scheme) {
                        $('#id_scheme').append($('<option>', {
                            value: scheme.id,
                            text: `${scheme.id}:${scheme.name}`
                        }));
                    });

                    // Restore the previous value of the scheme dropdown, if it exists
                    if (currentSchemeValue) {
                        $('#id_scheme').val(currentSchemeValue);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            // If no funder is selected, empty the scheme dropdown and add an empty option
            $('#id_scheme').empty().append('<option value="">---</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

And you are good to go.

Results/Output:

Funder lists
[image: Funder lists]

Add Project without funder selection
[image: Add Project scheme field without funder selection]

Add project scheme field on funder selection
[image: Add project scheme field on funder selection]

After saving Project lists (including empty scheme scenario)
[image: After saving Project lists (including empty scheme scenario)]

Hope this helps.

Happy coding!!